# How to adjust the position of subcaption and remove the letter numbering

Tags: captions, subfloats

I've created a figure containing some subfigures, and now I want to set their captions on the top (only in this individual figure) and remove the letter numbering, like (a) and (b). How can I do this?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{figures/subfigure1.png}}
    \hfill
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{figures/subfigure2.png}}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig1} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the folowing:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}  % <---
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]          %   <---
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty, % <---
                         position = top}    % <---
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{%
       \includegraphics{figures/subfigure1.png}}
    \hfill
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{%
        \includegraphics{figures/subfigure2.png}}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}                 % <---
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]  %   <---
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=empty,   % <---
                   position = top}      % <---
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{%
       \includegraphics{figures/subfigure1.png}}
    \hfill
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{%
        \includegraphics{figures/subfigure2.png}}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It solved my question. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Celdor, I know. In edited version try to delete `caption` package 
 but now I see, that I was in original post load it twice :-(. Now corrected. Thank you very much to point me on this.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\subfloat`. This assumes the images have the same height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
Caption 1 \\[1ex]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{tabular}%<---
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
Caption 2 \\[1ex]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{tabular}

\caption{This is the caption}
\label{fig1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]